# Aframe - How to Retrieve the text from textarea in Aframe

Tags: aframe

I Am unable to retrieve the text from the textarea as I just want to scale a box by typing the x-factor as the input. But the input is not being retrieved for some reason. Please help!...here is the code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>My A-Frame Scene</title>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-textarea-component/dist/aframe-textarea-component.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <a-scene>
      <a-sky color="#6EBAA7"></a-sky>
       <a-box id="redbox" position="3 2.5 -2" color="red"></a-box>
     <a-entity position="0 1 -2" id="inputText" textarea="backgroundColor:white; color:black; cols:5; rows:1;value:2;"></a-entity>
     <a-input postion="0 2 -2"></a-input>
     <a-text id="outputText"  position="0 2 -2" value="Hello"></a-text>
     <a-camera position="0 1 1">
      <a-cursor color="yellow"></a-cursor>
     </a-camera>
     <a-entity id="select-button" geometry="primitive: box" material="color:red" position="0 0 -2"></a>
      </a-scene>
      <script>
       var box = document.querySelector('#redbox')
       var printText = document.querySelector('#inputText');
       document.querySelector('#select-button').addEventListener('click',function(){
      box.setAttribute("scale", 
      {
       x : parseInt(printText.getAttribute('textarea').value),
       y : 1.5,
       z : 1.5
      }
      );
       });   
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Edit: I tried changing the code in javascript as follows:

parseInt(printText.getAttribute('textarea').text

It still does not work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` component does not expose the value directly but you can do:

`document.querySelector('#inputText').components.textarea.textarea.value`

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (0.3.0) of `aframe-textarea-component` now includes a `getText()` method which you can use to get the current text.

```js
document.querySelector('#inputText').components.textarea.getText();
```